# Food manufacturing during Ramadan

Tags: ramadan, food

What happens to Muslim country-based food processing/manufacturing companies during Ramadan? Do they shut down fully in the entirety of the fasting season? Do they shift the schedule such that operation activities are conducted during nighttime? Or do their non-Muslim workers continue the activities at a reasonable rate of work?

Answer (score 1):

Most countries work from 9-2 (with a slight variation) during the the month of Ramadan. In Saudi Arabia, senior level employees are not entitled to work reduced number of hours<sup>1</sup>.

Nothing closes entirely. Life moves on as usual.

Hotels/Cafeterias/etc in most Muslim countries don't serve anything during the day. Non Muslims can eat or drink during the day but most don't do it in front of their fellow Muslims as a gesture of respect.

---

1. http://www.bbc.com/news/business-19281749